# mysql GROUP BY query showing partial matches in email field

Tags: mysql, group-by, having

I have the following query for finding duplicate email addresses in mysql db .
It's returning partial match duplicate values , how can get only exact matches ?

```
SELECT id, email, date FROM mytable GROUP BY email HAVING COUNT(email) > 1
```

For example its giving following results:

1234567890@foo.net 
1234567890@bar.net

or

123@foo.com 
456@foo.com

or

100abc@gmail.com
100xyz@foo.com
100xhsy@bar.com

Comment: Run `SELECT * FROM your_table WHERE email = '1234567890@foo.net';` How many rows found?

Comment: Please learn how to use `GROUP BY`.  I don't see any aggregation so why `GROUP BY`?

Comment: You can use `GROUP BY` instead of  `DISTINCT` to collapse records with duplicate values into one result even if you aren't using an aggregate function like `COUNT` or `SUM`  which is what I believe @Abey was trying to do.

Answer (score 0):

@Abey I do this by joining the table into itself on the field I want to show is identical but where a truly unique value (like `id`) is different between the two records.

Here is how you would do that:

```
SELECT `mt1`.`id`, 
    `mt1`.`email`, 
    `mt1`.`date` 
FROM `mytable` AS `mt1`
JOIN `mytable` AS `mt2` ON `mt2`.`email` = `mt1`.`email`
    AND `mt2`.`id` <> `mt1`.`id`
GROUP BY `mt1`.`id`
```

If you want to have a distinct list of the duplicate emails and don't care to see each individual record, just trim out the other fields you are returning like this:

```
SELECT `mt1`.`email`
FROM `mytable` AS `mt1`
JOIN `mytable` AS `mt2` ON `mt2`.`email` = `mt1`.`email`
    AND `mt2`.`id` <> `mt1`.`id`
GROUP BY `mt1`.`email`
```

[Here is an example mocked up in sqlfiddle.](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/d0c0b0/1)

Hope this helps!